# Adding taper to mayavi line plots

Tags: python, visualization, mayavi

I am trying to use Mayavi to visualize neurons. I have been using this paradigm:

```
x1 = np.hstack(x1)
y1 = np.hstack(y1)
z1 = np.hstack(z1)
s1 = np.hstack(s1)
connections1 = np.vstack(connections1)
src1 = mlab.pipeline.scalar_scatter(x1, y1, z1, s1)
src1.mlab_source.dataset.lines = connections1
src1.update()
lines1 = mlab.pipeline.stripper(src1)
mlab.pipeline.surface(lines1,colormap='jet',line_width=3,opacity=1)
mlab.show()
```

[image]

This has worked fine to get simple trees plotted but I'm having trouble finding suitable approaches to changing line_width so that it has a taper...can mayavi even do this?